# Number of possibilities arranging $k$ balls in $t$ cells.

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of possibilities arranging $k$ balls in $t$ cells, where:

- More then one ball in a cell **is allowed**.
- balls are different (e.g. every ball has a unique color).

I understood the answer is $t^k$ but what is the explanation for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case, the best way to understand basic combinatorics is to write out a step-by-step procedure for constructing the kind of arrangement you want.  For your problem you could do it this way:

(1) choose a cell for the first ball. . . . . $t$ ways of doing this
(2) choose a cell for the second ball. . . . . $t$ ways of doing this, because the same cell is allowed

. . . . . and so on. . . . .

($k$) choose a cell for the $k$th and last ball. . . . . still $t$ ways of doing this.

Now since you have to do (1) **and** (2) **and**. . . . . **and** ($k$), your final answer is obtained by multiplying all the partial answers:
$$t\,t\,\cdots\,t=t^k\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Each ball has $k$ choices of where it is put.  As the choices are independent, you multiply them.